# Laravel best strategy to serve requests from API and form at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, laravel-7

Using Laravel 7.*, I'm tasked with creating a simple app to send requests for payment, the user fill a form and send the data then I validate the user inputs and create a new Payment instance.

Then the user is redirected back to the same page. (Of course there are other requests for listing all payments and updating a payment):

```php
   //In PaymentController.php

   public function store()
    {
        $inputData = $this->validateRequest();

        $person = $this->personRepository->findOneByAttribute('id_number', request('id_number'));

        if ($person instanceof Person) {
            $this->paymentRepository->create($inputData, $person);
            return back()->with('successMessage', 'Your payment request registered successfully.');
        } else {
            return back()->with('failureMessage', 'Shoot! Cannot find a peron with the given Identification Number.')->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Everything is fine, but I need to implement a Restful API to do the same request and get a valid json response, Assuming there is no front-end JavaScript framework, what is the best approach to achieve this goal?

Should I create a separate controller? Or Simply check whether request is sent from a traditional form or an API client? Am I missing a design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simply way would be to check what kind of response you should send back:

```
   //In PaymentController.php

   public function store()
    {
        $inputData = $this->validateRequest();

        $person = $this->personRepository->findOneByAttribute('id_number', request('id_number'));

        if ($person instanceof Person) {
            $this->paymentRepository->create($inputData, $person);
            if (request()->expectsJson()) {
                return response('', 201); // Just a successfully created response 
            }
            return back()->with('successMessage', 'Your payment request registered successfully.');
        } else {
            if (request()->expectsJson()) {
                return response()->json([ 'error' => 'Not found' ], 404); // You can change the error code and message (or remove the message) as needed
            }
            return back()->with('failureMessage', 'Shoot! Cannot find a person with the given Identification Number.')->withInput();
        }
    }
```

You can of course choose to encapsulate this in a class that implements the [`Responsible`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/Responsable.php) interface

```
class PaymentResponse implements Responsible {
     private $success;
     public function __construct($success) {
           $this->success = $success;
     }

     public function toResponse($request) {
         if ($this->success) {
            if (request()->expectsJson()) {
                return response()->json([ 'error' => 'Not found' ], 404); // You can change the error code and message (or remove the message) as needed
            }
            return back()->with('failureMessage', 'Shoot! Cannot find a person with the given Identification Number.')->withInput();
          } 
          if (request()->expectsJson()) {
              return response()->json([ 'error' => 'Not found' ], 404); // You can change the error code and message (or remove the message) as needed
          }
          return back()->with('failureMessage', 'Shoot! Cannot find a person with the given Identification Number.')->withInput();
     }
  
}
```

then your code would be:

```
//In PaymentController.php

   public function store()
    {
        $inputData = $this->validateRequest();

        $person = $this->personRepository->findOneByAttribute('id_number', request('id_number'));

        if ($person instanceof Person) {
            $this->paymentRepository->create($inputData, $person);
            return new PaymentResponse(true);
        } else {
            return new PaymentResponse(false);
        }
    }
```

You can of course also extract the controller logic to a separate library and then have two separate controller methods and still use the responsible object if you want. It really is dependent on your use case and what works best for you

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I will try and test your second suggestion.

Comment: Your solution works for the cases that we redirect back the user, what if user wants to see all the payments and we return a view?

Comment: In that case I think you probably need a separate controller action. It might be good to extract the controller logic in a separate library so you can re-use it if needed but since the response will be different. I mean you can pass a parameter to the same controller action and pass that parameter to the `Repsonsible` object to determine what kind of response to send but this will make the controller action have too many responsibilities IMO

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach would be to make use of service-repository pattern. You wrap your application service in a separate class. A service is the interactor between controller and repository. The flow would look like `[request] -> [controller] -> [service] -> [repository]`.

By leveraging this pattern you can then resuse your service in different areas in the app. For example you can have a controller specific for serving traditional web apps, and a controller for serving SPA, by returning JSON data, but serve the same business process.

E.g. :

**Payment Response:**

```
class PaymentStoreResponse
{
    protected $message;
    protected $code;
    protected $extraData;

    public function __construct($message, $code, $extraData = "")
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->extraData = $extraData;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
    
    public function getExtraData()
    {
        return $this->extraData;
    }
}
```

**Payment Service:**

```
function store($data)
{
    $person = $this->personRepository->findOneByAttribute('id_number', $data('id_number'));

    if ($person instanceof Person) {
        $this->paymentRepository->create($inputData, $person);
        return new PaymentResponse("paymentSuccess", 201, "successMessage");
    } else {
        return new PaymentResponse("notFound", 404, "failureMessage");
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// App\Controllers\Web\PaymentController.php
function store(Request $request)
{
    $inputData = $this->validateRequest();
    $response = $this->paymentService->store($inputData);
    
    return back()->with($response->getExtraData(), $response->getMessage()) 
}


// App\Controllers\Api\PaymentController.php
function store(Request $request)
{
    // validation might be different because
    // api might need to authenticate with jwt etc.
    $inputData = $this->validateRequest();
    $response = $this->paymentService->store($inputData);

    return response()->json(['message' => $response->getMessage()], $response->getCode());
}
```

This will result in a cleaner controller because the controller will only handle request validation and response, while delegating business process to the service class (payment service). The business logic is also centralized in the service layer, which means if there is a change to the business, it will apply to the API controller and Web controller. Hence, it will save you from a refactoring nightmare.

You can explore different architectures such as Clean Architecture + DDD. It will make your development experience better, achieving a centralized domain logic, and low coupling between layers by depending on abstractions.